# Drop-Down Autocompletion in Emacs' Python-Mode

Tags: python, emacs

I have installed python-mode and have auto-complete working with `M-Tab`, but when I execute it, the possible completions end up in my other open frame. Is there a way to get emacs to,

1. Use a dropdown menu to show me potential completions (or a Vim-style quick-fix frame)
2. Automatically fill in potential completions as I press `M-tab` over and over?

**EDIT:** After a bit of surfing I've realized that [auto-complete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) is the plugin I'm looking for (at least with respect to drop-down menus), but I'm still not sure how to get `python-mode`'s candidate detection into auto-complete.  I tried `ac-python`, but it seems like it was freezing emacs...

Answer (score 1):

One of the authors of https://github.com/auto-complete is also creating [emacs-jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi), which is basically autocompletion for Python in Emacs (It uses the [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) autocompletion library).

Answer (score 0):

M-TAB does complete, not auto-complete. "Auto" means no key is needed. Auto-completion is delivered by several environments, mostly either based on company-mode or auto-complete.el

http://gabrielelanaro.github.com/emacs-for-python, the latter

https://github.com/pdee/pdee, Pymacs/company based

or via bazaar, also Pymacs/company based

bzr branch lp:python-mode/components-python-mode